# Need to load jqgrid based on dropdownlist change Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I use the following script for loading the data into jqgrid based on the drop down value change event

**It will work only one time.If I select second option in drop down the grid cant able to hit the URL**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#skill").on('change', function () {


            $("#Jobtable").jqGrid({
                url: '/Admin/ViewSelectedJobs?skill=' + $("#skill").val(),
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames: ['ID', 'Title'],
                colModel: [
                            { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true },
                            { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true }

                ],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                viewrecords: true,
                loadonce: true,
                gridview: true
});
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unload grid first and then load it again using below jQuery :

```
$("#Jobtable").jqGrid('GridUnload');
```

So your code should be :

```
$("#skill").on('change', function () {

           $("#Jobtable").jqGrid('GridUnload');
            $("#Jobtable").jqGrid({
                url: '/Admin/ViewSelectedJobs?skill=' + $("#skill").val(),
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames: ['ID', 'Title'],
                colModel: [
                            { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true },
                            { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true }

                ],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                viewrecords: true,
                loadonce: true,
                gridview: true
});
```